# What does "mastering Java EE" mean?

Tags: jakarta-ee

Often I hear people say, "I know Java EE", or "I've mastered Java EE".

What does that mean: when can I say that, or what would I need to learn to know Java EE?

Comment: If they say "I've masterede J2EE" they lie.

Answer (score 6):

Java EE is the Java Enterprise Platform, or officially "Java Platform, Enterprise Edition". The naming convention was changed by Sun some time ago and the most recent versions are now called Java EE 5 and 6.

The Java Enterprise Edition is an extension to the Java standard library which is composend of a number of components and application as well as security models to provide a ready-to-use framework for building complex and distributed Java applications. It also introduces the concept of a "container", which is usually an application server providing all or a subset of the standard J2EE components, to allow the transfer of Java EE applications between servers without rewriting the complete application (there are obviously some caveats here in practice, though).

"Knowing Java EE" could be interpreted as *being aware and understanding the concept of all Java EE components and having used some of them in an application design already*.

Obvioulsy different people will have different ideas here, but I'd say if you have used Servlets, JSPs, EJBs and other data access components and grasp the concept of JMS, JNDI, the underlying XML technologies and web services, you should be able to claim knowledge of Java EE.

If you want to **learn** more about the different components, Sun has a quite comprehensive [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/) available.

For a complete overview of all technologies involved in the Java Enterprise Platform, there is a [full list](http://java.sun.com/javaee/technologies/index.jsp) at Sun's website, even though that one only refers to the latest versions Java EE 5 and 6, not J2EE to be precise.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to master Java EE, you should at least read through the "Java EE Tutorials" and "Java EE core patterns". Knowing Java EE means you have ideas of the Java EE components and concepts as  Chris said. Perhaps you should get through the Sun certification of Java EE too if you want to master the Java EE.

By the way, software building is a practical activity. You can't master it well unless you have rich real engineering experience.